# Grouping Date and time Fields with Null or Zero Value Fields

Tags: sql, datetime, grouping

I want to group these fields to single row.

**EDIT :**

I want to write sql statement to group all four line to one line as I want to group the values by removing default date from 1st column and 0 values from all other columns

```
Visit_Date  Receipt_Time        Visit_Time          Prs_Time

2018-05-01  00:28:11.3700000    00:00:00.0000000    00:00:00.0000000

1900-01-01  00:00:00.0000000    00:37:22.0000000    00:00:00.0000000

1900-01-01  00:00:00.0000000    00:00:00.0000000    00:37:22.0000000
```

These Records should be in single like

```
2018-05-01     00:28:11.3700000       00:37:22.0000000    00:37:22.0000000
```

Comment: What's your criteria for a grouping? Have you attempted to write any SQL?

Comment: I want to write sql statement to group all four line to one line as I want to group the values by removing default date from 1st column and  0 values from all other columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select max(Visit_Date) as Visit_Date,
       max(Receipt_Time) as Receipt_Time,
       max(Visit_Time) as Visit_Time,
       max(Prs_Time) as Prs_Time
from t;
```

Your data format is rather . . . arcane.  I suspect these are the results from some query.  You should fix the query to generate the data as you really need it.

Comment: Yes this is the result of 3 queries using the union

Comment: How can I fix this to single line result.

Comment: @MuhammadShahid . . . This query returns one row.